# JsonConverter does not work on model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I got the following model

```
public class SignDocumentsModel
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(BinaryConverter))]
    public byte[][] Documents { get; set; }

    public bool Detached { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{requestId}/sign")]
public Task<IHttpActionResult> SignDocuments([FromUri] Guid requestId, SignDocumentsModel parameters)
{
    return SomeKindOfProcessing(requestGuid, parameters);
}
```

Now, when I perform a request with the Postman

```
POST
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "Detached": "true",
    "Documents": [
        "bG9weXN5c3RlbQ=="
    ]
}
```

I suppose the Documents property should be populated with byte arrays decoded from Base64 strings posted in request content, although in fact the property is empty (in case its type in model is `List<byte[]>` or `byte[][]`, and `null` in case of `IEnumerable<byte[]>`).

Why JsonConverter doesn't being called on request body deserialization during model binding? How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried removing `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(BinaryConverter))]`?

In my test setup, the model binds successfully after I remove that attribute.

*Edit: a bit more info...*

According to the [Json.NET Serialization Guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm), a `byte[]` will serialize to a base64 string by default. Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/BinaryConverter.cs), it looks like `BinaryConverter` is meant to be used with `System.Data.Linq.Binary` or `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary`--not `byte[]`.